# How do I find the smallest surrounding rectangle of a set of 2D points in Shapely?

Tags: python, shapely

How do I find the msmallest surrounding rectangle (which is possibly rotated) of a set of 2D points in Shapely?

Comment: Well, if you find the minimum x and the minimum y, and the maximum x and the maximum y, you will have the upper left and lower right corners of the bounding rectangle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create the smallest surrounding rectangle in Shapely, first construct a MultiPoint from a sequence of points then use the *minimum_rotated_rectangle* property (which is in the BaseGeometry class).

```python
from shapely.geometry import MultiPoint, Polygon

points = [(0, 0), (2, 2), (10, 4), (5, 5), (8, 8)]

# create a minimum rotated rectangle containing all the points
polygon = MultiPoint(points).minimum_rotated_rectangle
print(polygon)
```

**Output:**

```
POLYGON ((2.9999999999999996 -2.9999999999999996, 10.999999999999998 4.999999999999998, ...
```

The example set of points are displayed below in red and the bounding box is in blue.

[image: MBR plot]

If want to create an envelope around the points that is the smallest rectangle (with sides parallel to the coordinate axes) containing all the points then call the *envelope* property on the object.

```
polygon = MultiPoint(points).envelope
```

[image: envelope]

Comment: This is just the bounding rectangle, I want the one that has then minimum area (it's likely rotated).

Comment: @nickponline - use minimum_rotated_rectangle function in Shapely.